# Can I add an extension method to a LIST<>?

Tags: c#

I have this code:

```
public static List<Phrase> selectedPhrases;
```

and

```
if  (!App.selectedPhrases.Any(x => x.Viewed == false))
                return;
```

Is there any way that I could change the way I declare selectedPhrases so that I could do that last check in this way:

```
if  (App.selectedPhrases.AllViewed())
    return;
```

I heard about extension methods but is that possible to create one for a List like in my code?

Comment: What do you think Linq is?

Comment: Yes, it is possible. Learn the syntax for an extension method first, then try to apply it to a `List<Phrase>.`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can write extension method on List, for your example, Phrase

```
public static class Extension
{
    public static bool AllViewed(this List<Phrase> source)
    {
        return source.All(x=>x.Viewed)
    }
}
```

Btw, You don't need to check `!Any(x=>c.Viewed==false)`, there is the option to use .All() Extension method as shown in the code above

You can read more on the syntax of extension methods [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/extension-methods).

You might be also interested to read on how Linq extension methods are implemented by looking at some of source code [at referencesource](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#system.core/system/linq/Enumerable.cs) .

Comment: It’s a good answer and I know OP asked for this, but I would argue that introducing an extension method `AllViewed()` that only does `All(x=>x.Viewed)` doesn’t really provide a benefit as the latter shows the intent quite well and isn’t much longer anyway.

Comment: @ckuri True, may be OP was unsure about All() and had struck to Any. That's why i thought i would mentioned about All as well in the answer. But like you said, All(x=>x.Viewed) does the job well and extension method might not be quite required in this particular scenario.

Answer (score 1):

You can create an extension method in a static class:

```
public static class PhraseExtensions
{
    public static bool AllViewed(this List<Phrase> phrases)
    {
        return !phrases.Any(p => !p.Viewed);
        // phrases.All(p => p.Viewed); would be better suited.
    }
}
```

See the documentation about extensions here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/extension-methods